# Ler de um ficheiro txt através de fscanf usando vector

Tags: c++, arquivo, struct, vector

Eu tenho o seguinte

```
while(!feof(f)){
        (*ptr).push_back(carro());
        fscanf (f, "%d", (*ptr)[add].id);
        fscanf (f, "%s", (*ptr)[add].marca);
        add++;
}
```

Onde *ptr é &vector, um vector de uma struct carro, já consegui com que grava-se mas por algum motivo que não compreendo o programa, quando carrega do ficheiro, rebenta.

O ficheiro, caso seja importante, contêm:

```
1 VW
2 Seat
3 Audi
```

E a struct é a seguinte:

```
typedef struct Auto{

   int id;
   char marca[50];

}carro;
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que vc deveria usar a própria função fscanf como condição, pois ao alcançar o fim do arquivo ela retorna EOF.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Automovil {
    int id;
    char marca[50];

};

void lerArquivo(vector<Automovil> &lista){
    FILE *f = fopen("autos.txt", "r");
    Automovil dados;
    while ( fscanf(f,"%d %s", &dados.id, dados.marca) != EOF ) {
        lista.push_back( dados );
    }
    fclose(f);

}

int main () {
    vector<Automovil> lista;

    lerArquivo(lista);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<lista.size() ; i++ ) {
        cout << "vetor[" << i << "] = ID: " << lista[i].id << ", Marca: " << lista[i].marca << endl;   
    }


    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Porem em c++ o correto é usar streams para ler desde arquivos.
Um conselho... 
Não use a palavra auto já que ela faz parte do padrão c++11 e é uma palavra reservada da linguagem.